# Network Path in JSON stringified dictionary

Tags: c#, json, tfs, build

I'm trying to start a build on TFS 2017 via JSON as shown in this example:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build

This is my JSON:

```
{
"definition": 
{
    "id": 167
},
"sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
"parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"false\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"release\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"any cpu\",\"PushInfoXmlFilePath\":\"\\\\08tfs02\\PushInformation\\PushInfo896.xml\"}"
}
```

Looking into the event log I saw this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Bad JSON escape sequence: \P.
>   Path 'PushInfoXmlFilePath', line 1, position 115.

I have tried it replacing the network path **\"\\08tfs02\PushInformation\PushInfo896.xml\"** with a simple **\"test\"** and then it works without error.

How can I make it work with the network path?

Comment: Did try the method below, does it solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this format for your json file:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "id": 167
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "system.debug": "false",
    "BuildConfiguration": "release",
    "BuildPlatform": "any cpu",
    "PushInfoXmlFilePath": "\\\\08tfs02\\PushInformation\\PushInfo896.xml"
  }
}
```

You'd better not put all the Parameters in one line.